# ArrayList values changed without modification in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm developing one Android Application.

I have one **screen-A** with **show** button. When user clicks on this **show** button, then I'm showing one dialog  which contains **Listview with checkboxes** and two buttons **submit** , **cancel**.

```
editGroupUsersDialog = new Dialog(mcontext);
editGroupUsersDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
editGroupUsersDialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_group_users_layout);
editGroupUsersDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
editGroupUsersDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
editGroupUsersDialog.show();

ArrayList<User> users = //got from the server;
```

Now I have taken one more static variable in the **screnn-A** and initialized with above users.

```
public static ArrayList<User> editUsers = users;
```

Now I have created adapter object and send the static users to the adapter.

```
ListView users_listview = (ListView)editGroupUsersDialog.findViewById(R.id.user_listView);
EditGroupUsersAdapter edit_group_users_adapter = new EditGroupUsersAdapter(
                    mcontext, edit_group_users);
users_listview.setAdapter(edit_group_users_adapter);
```

Now when the user check or uncheck any item in the dialog, then i'm setting the state of that item in the bean class **User**.

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // add this line too for getting position of clicked
                    int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    Log.v("Position is:", ""+pos);  
                    Log.v("Befoer checkbox status is:", ""+GroupsAdapter.edit_group_users.get(position).isSelected());
                if(!GroupsAdapter.edit_group_users.get(pos).isSelected()) {                     
                    //set the value to true in the user bean
                    GroupsAdapter.edit_group_users.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                    //checkbox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    //set the value to false in the user bean
                    GroupsAdapter.edit_group_users.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                    //checkbox.setChecked(false);
                }                                            
            } 
        });
```

Here i'm changing the state in static user variable only. i.e. **GroupsAdapter.edit_group_users** which is of type **ArrayList**

But the objects int non static variable **users** of type **ArrayList** is also changing.

I don't know what was the wrong I'm doing here.

**The main purpose i'm taking another static variable of type **ArrayList** is to store the modified **User** objects. But I don't want to change the original users which are available in **users** variable.

Please tell me how to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both your static and non-static Arraylist are referencing to `list of user`.

Now say for some user A, you changes its state from X to Y. Then, this change will be reflected to both Arraylist because both Arraylist are `pointing to` same object, and you are changing the `state of object`.